# Python - If a "full" word is inside a text, print out else don't

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am having issue where I want to compare a word inside a text - meaning if there is a word that contains inside a text it should print out.

The issue is that I am having let say I have a word that is "lo" - and my text is = "hello guys, my name is Stackoverflow" - it will print out that whole text there is a lo inside this text which are inside "hello" and "stackoverflow"

my question is how can I make whenever I want to search for a word such as "lo" it should take it as a word and not print out if it etc. contains inside a word such as "hello" or "stackoverflow" - Only print out if it has the word "lo"?

```
keywords = ["Lo"]
for text in keywords:
   if text in text_roman():
      print("Yay found word")
```

Comment: Python's regex library is probably the (best) way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split up the string into words then test for the substring in each of the words.

```
For word in s.split():
  If q in word:
    Print word
```

Comment: I tried this solution and it helped me to solve the problem :) Thanks! Im sure the other guys below also wrote good solutions!

Answer (score 0):

use `string.find()` . It returns the index of the substring you're looking for, and `-1` if not found. So you can apply `if` statement to check whether it is a substring or not.

```
s='Hello there Stack!'
if (s.find('llo')!=-1):
    print('String found')
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: if loop?  a if isn't a loop you mean while or for loop here right? .. Besides the current code only find one match the topicstarter is looking for multple matches within a string.. "contains inside a word such as **"hello"** or **"stackoverflow"** - Only print out if it has the word **"lo"**?"

Comment: @RaymondNijland We can use `count` function for that.. So alternatively, we can use `count` also to check for the substring.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this but there are like... 400 edge cases that will make this a problem.

```
text = "This is my text"
keywords = ["Lo"]
if len(set(text.split()).intersection(set(keywords))) > 0:
    print("Yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is probably to use a regex. You can play around with regexes [here](https://regex101.com/) and figure out how to implement them in python [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
import re

target_strings = ["lo", "stack", "hell", "cow", "hello", "overf"]

for target in target_strings:
  re_target = re.compile(r"\b({})\b".format(target), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
  if re.search(re_target, "Hello stack overflow lo"):
    print(target)

>>> lo
>>> stack
>>> hello
```